# list picker in popup windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, popup

I am using a list picker in popup. But when I click on list picker, its full mode opens behind popup. How can I make my list picker full mode window to appear above popup.
MY list picker is in the user control called WindowsPhoneControl1

```
Popup Mypopup = new Popup();

            Mypopup.Height = 300;

            Mypopup.Width = 400;

            Mypopup.VerticalOffset = 100;

            WindowsPhoneControl1 Mycontrol = new WindowsPhoneControl1();

            Mypopup.Child = Mycontrol;

            Mypopup.IsOpen = true;
```

i didn't find a solution 
thank you

Comment: Just add a screenshot of whats happening to you. We would get to an alternate if you don't get any.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the `Popup` in XAML.

such as so:

```
<Popup IsOpen="true" Name="MyPopup" Height="300" Width="400" VerticleOffset="100"/>
```

Make sure IsOpen is true, then try to right-click on the `ListPicker` and choose it's order: bring-to-front.

I know it's simple, but I didn't see you mention trying it, so give it a shot!